# Why was I given just 85 mosaic tile sheets when I purchased 88 square feet?

Tags: tile

I picked up my tile order yesterday. I got these "1'x1'" meshes of 1" diameter hexagonal tiles. It was explained to me that you buy them by the total square feet. I wanted to get 10% more than I needed and I needed 80 square feet, so I paid for 88 square feet. I got 8 boxes, each with 11, 1'x1' meshes. When I was unloading them at home, I noted one of the boxes was open and only had 8 meshes in it. When I called and pointed out that I was shy 3 meshes, they explained that somehow, that was correct, but I couldn't understand how that works out.

Besides that, the meshes are not 1'x1'. I measured them and they are 11" by 11.5"?!  I mean, if that's shrinkflation, then whatever - I won't blame them for that, but what's up with being 3 sheets short?

The tile is Merola Carrara. I could not find an on-line listing for it, but here's what the box says and pictures of my measurements. It was hard to hold the camera and the tape measure at the same time, so although the horizontal measurement looks like 11 5/8, it is actually 11 1/2. Horizontally, I measured a single row. Vertically I measured from the tip of one to the valley of the other.

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here's the row for these tiles on the invoice:

[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a single, clear, specific question. Ask just one per post.

Comment: How did you measure the panels? Obviously a hex tile layout has jogs in it and angles on some edges. Measure short point to long point in each direction. Tile is often sized with a standard-ish grout gap in mind, so consider that as well.

Comment: There are 1/16" tile spacers available at any/all of the Orange, Blue, or Green BigBox stores as well as Amazon, etc. I would imagine, like many building materials, there's some difference between the _common_ dimensions of the tile mats versus the _nominal_ dimensions. Similar to what you find with 2x4 lumber, etc.

Comment: What does the labelling on the box state for per-box coverage?

Comment: You did not get 88 SQ ft. by any method of math.

Comment: once you remove them and grout between the tiles, they should be a square foot, if not slightly more.

Comment: @dandavis, the grout lines would have to be about 1/2 inch wide. Not likely for 1"x"1 inch tiles on mesh.

Comment: Can you link the specification sheet for the tiles please?

Comment: For some reason a box is three sheets short, and supplier didn't notice when they shipped them to you. Supplier is now trying to bullsh1t you into accepting that this is correct, to avoid the cost of shipping the extra. Ask them to show you the calculation that they did to arrive at 85 sheets = 88 sq ft.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a vendor not willing to take responsibility for not shipping the correct/complete order. I'd suggest contacting them, asking for the additional tiles, and if they refuse again, ask them to initiate a return, telling them that you'll just buy them elsewhere since they won't make it right.

Comment: @SiHa I actually picked them up from the store. I couldn't really understand they guy's explanation, but I had the impression that he intentionally removed the 3 sheets himself at the store because somehow it was more than I ordered. The box was ripped open, in fact.

Comment: Not that I need the question re-opened because people are answering in the comments, but I have no idea what info I can add that I haven't already supplied, other than further updates from the store when I next speak to them. But the answer seems to be that the vendor is just wrong and there's no logical explanation for the missing sheets. Is the 11x11.5 thing just shrinkflation and you're expected to anticipate that and buy more?

Comment: @hepcat72 no, it's not shrinkflation. The box says each sheet is 1'x1'. It's clearly slightly under that, which is perhaps allowable because they are a hexagonal matrix. If anything you should have three sheets *extra*. Again, I'd be asking the vendor to show you his calculation for removing the three sheets, and if he can't provide it, insist on the missing sheets. If he doesn't provide it/them, take it up with whatever organization exists where you are, to go to you have a grievance with a trader.

Comment: @SiHa, I spoke with them this morning on my commute and they had already "ordered" the 3 missing sheets (implicitly acknowledging the mistake). But, I also redid my calculations (because I'd overlooked the fact that I wanted the hexes on the back of the shower niche and had underestimated the size of the closet - but also, I accounted for the 11"x11.5" sheets in the tile calculator I'd used and it came up with 110 sheets needed (with the suggested extra 10% for mistakes), so I ordered 2 more boxes in addition to the 3 missing sheets. Should be in by Friday.

Comment: As far as the missing 3 sheets, that is on the retailer to fix. Open boxes can happen for a *lot* of reasons. A few years ago I picked up a faucet at Home Depot. It was missing one key part. The box I got was factory sealed, so I figured it was the manufacturer's problem. I contacted the manufacturer. They sent me the part for free. But the wrong part - apparently two slightly different models in production with that part being different. So I ended up going back to Home Depot. They were *fantastic* and went to the plumbing aisle with me to open boxes until we found exactly the part I needed.

Comment: I would have been perfectly fine if they had grabbed a matching appropriate part by itself from the hardware/plumbing parts area because I know they would now have an open box with a missing part. They insisted that they would worry about that but that the concern right now was that I would get the part I needed! That was great service. The point though (aside from Home Depot has great service, at least that time) is that it could be something like a previous customer opened a box and found 3 sheets damaged, went back to the store and they replaced the three sheets (as they should) but then

Comment: instead of contacting the manufacturer, they left a torn open box on the shelf for the next victim (you!). It may not have been "malicious," it may just have been "stupid." [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor)